# Safari css width transition not working with different unit measurements

Tags: css, safari, webkit, css-transitions

I'm having an issue with `-webkit-transition` in Safari. These transitions work fine in Chrome, FF, and IE10 (using the non-prefixed transition property).

In my site, there are 3 panels that can be viewed. The main one opens by default and the other 2 are collapsed on the right of the window showing a sliver of their content. When a collapsed panel is clicked an additional class is added to it via JS and it transitions to 100% width.

**CSS:**

```
.panel-1{
  width: 100%;
}

.panel-2{
    width: 8rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 500;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.panel-2:hover{
     width: 10rem;
}

.panel-2.panel-open{
     width: 100%;
}

.panel-3{
    width: 4rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 501;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.panel-3:hover{
     width: 6rem;
}

.panel-3.panel-open{
     width: 100%;
}
```

The problem seems to be with the difference of measurement units. The hover transitions work as intended (`rem` to `rem`), however the width transition (`rem` to `%`) on "panel-open" skips the transition and just snaps open. If I switch the default width to a percentage instead of `rem`, the transition works again. I can't do this however as it is a fluid site and the panel collapsed widths need to be static and not relative.

I have attempted to add a `min-width` in `%`, but that has not helped. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please provide example in here or jsfiddle.

Comment: What is the relation between `.panel-1`, `.panel-2` and `.panel-3`? Please provide the html or a working jsFiddle. LE: i just noticed the date of this question. Sergey, I'm wondering if it was worth editing it and bringing it back. BigRedEd probably forgot he has a SE account by now.

Answer (score 2):

Transitions on `width` are a problem. Try `max-width`.

Answer (score 0):

Transitioning a `width` is problematic in my experience. You can convert this to using `left` and `right` values instead of using width. `width: 20%;` would be the same as `left: 80%; right: 0;`, and `width: 50%;` would be `left: 25%; right: 25%;`. Here's a codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWaJzN

```js
document.getElementById("wrapper").addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (this.classList.contains('center')) {
    this.classList.remove('center');
  }
  else {
   this.classList.add('center');
  }
});
```

```css
.container { 
  width: 550px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: teal;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 20%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

#wrapper.center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}


h3 {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="card">
      <h3>click here</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</section>
```